# Why does SQL Server treat this same SQL differently?

Tags: sql-server, doctrine-orm, nullable

I have a `CREATE TABLE` script. When I run it via the *command line*, it does not create nullable columns. When I run it *manually* via SQL Server's Query Browser, it does. What am I missing?

## Via command line

I'm attempting to use Doctrine 2's command line schema-tool to create my schema in SQL Server 2014 (1).

Here is the SQL it creates from my entity's annotations (2) (note, `address_2` is nullable) (the spacing and arrow are mine):

```
# dump the SQL Doctrine will use
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
CREATE TABLE company (
    id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    address_1 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 

    address_2 NVARCHAR(255),   <-- it should be optional

    city NVARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, 
    email NVARCHAR(255), 
    name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    phone NVARCHAR(12), 
    state NVARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    zip NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

# execute the command
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

According to SQL Server Profiler, SQL Server receives the following commands (note, `address_2` should still be nullable) (the spacing and arrow are mine):

```
set textsize 20971520 
go
set textsize 2147483647
set quoted_identifier on

go
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
go
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
go
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
go
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
go
CREATE TABLE company (
    id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    address_1 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 

    address_2 NVARCHAR(255),   <-- it should be optional

    city NVARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, 
    email NVARCHAR(255), 
    name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    phone NVARCHAR(12), 
    state NVARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    zip NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
go
```

**However, when you inspect the created table, `address_2` is `NOT NULL`.**

Here's a screenshot of the table browser as well as the output of [SQL Server's equivalent to MySQL's `SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319334/show-create-commands-for-table-in-sql-management-studio-2008) (the spacing and arrow are mine):

[Table created via command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdU2C.png)

```
USE [mydatabase]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[company]    Script Date: 11/11/2016 9:47:03 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [address_1] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,

    [address_2] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,   <-- it's not optional!

    [city] [nvarchar](31) NOT NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [state] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [zip] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

## Via the Query Browser

Now, here comes the fun part.

If you run the *exact* same commands that SQL Server received (according to the SQL Server Profiler) in the SQL Server Query Browser (the spacing and arrow are mine):

```
set textsize 20971520 
go
set textsize 2147483647
set quoted_identifier on

go
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
go
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
go
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
go
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
go
CREATE TABLE company (
    id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    address_1 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 

    address_2 NVARCHAR(255),   <-- it should be optional

    city NVARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, 
    email NVARCHAR(255), 
    name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    phone NVARCHAR(12), 
    state NVARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    zip NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
go
```

**The `address_2` field is `NULL`**:

[Table created via query browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8koE.png)

```
USE [mydatabase]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[company]    Script Date: 11/11/2016 9:49:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [address_1] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,

    [address_2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,  <-- it's optional!

    [city] [nvarchar](31) NOT NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [state] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [zip] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

## Conclusion

What in the world is going on? **How can the *same* SQL script produce *different* results?**

I've searched the web for help, but I can't seem to find an explanation or solution for the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

In my mind:

- The `SET` flags shouldn't matter, because the query works in the SQL Server Query Browser with them. Plus, I've looked into them, and none of them seem to change T-SQL's behavior towards optional columns.
- The hoops I jumped through to connect Doctrine to SQL Server from a *nix machine shouldn't matter (1), because the commands that reach SQL Server (as shown by the SQL Server Profiler) work in the Query Browser.

---

Footnotes

1. I'm connecting Doctrine to SQL Server from a CentOS machine. I'm using FreeTDS to connect to SQL server, and I'm using a third-party DBlib Doctrine Driver. I know that is convoluted haha.
2. I haven't included the entity, because I'm not sure it'll help. The SQL generated by Doctrine is correct.

Comment: [`SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187375). And now you know why you should always be explicit.

Comment: Spot on remark from Jeroen :). Small question: when you mention `SQL Server Query Browser`, do you mean `SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are my hero! I couldn't change the SQL Doctrine created. But, I set the global option on the database (right click database > properties > options > set ANSI NULL Default to true), and it fixed it! Lesson learned! Can you add your _comment_ as an _answer_ instead so I can accept it?

Comment: @TT. Yes'r. Haha sorry. I do mean SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I thought the area where you write queries in SSMS is called the Query Browser haha. I'm new to SQL Server. I've spent most of my time in the MySQL world.

Comment: @Jack: if you insist. I may have gone a *little* overboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify whether or not a column is `NULL` or `NOT NULL` in your `CREATE TABLE`, things get complicated. Unnecessarily so, you might say.

In their wisdom (or, more probably, to cater to backwards compatibility) the developers of SQL Server saw fit to have this governed by no less than three options:

- If the (session-level) option `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` is `ON`, then unspecified columns are nullable.
- If the (session-level) option `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF` is `ON`, then unspecified columns are not nullable.
- These options are exclusive, so they cannot both be `ON`. They can, however, both be `OFF`. If they are, then nullability is governed by the database-level option `ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT`, which can be either `ON` (unspecified columns are nullable) or `OFF` (unspecified columns are not nullable).

The majority of clients will connect through ODBC or OLE DB, which will both set `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` (it's not called `ANSI` for nothing, after all). This means most "modern" clients will always get nullable columns if nothing is specified. But clients that connect through the (ancient) DB-Library, and apparently also FreeTDS in this particular setup, do not specify these options, and so the database setting comes into play.<sup>1</sup>

On database creation, the settings are taken from the `model` database and are [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186388). They emphasize backwards compatibility and it should come as no surprise that `ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT` defaults to `OFF` for newly created databases. But here at least you have the opportunity to step in and change things, with

```
ALTER DATABASE [db] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON
```

Whether or not it's a good idea to do this depends on your setup. If possible, you should connect through drivers that set the `ANSI_NULL_DLFT_ON` option (or do so explicitly yourself) so all applications, old and new, get what they expect. Setting defaults on the database (or even on `model` so all databases inherit them) could be a good thing because it ensures consistency, or it could be a bad thing because it breaks old clients.

As [Books Online wisely notes on this subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187375):

> For a more reliable operation of Transact-SQL scripts that are used in
>   databases with different nullability settings, it is better to specify
>   `NULL` or `NOT NULL` in `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements.

If the Doctrine authors had done this, you could have forgotten all about the above text.

---

<sup>1</sup> While FreeTDS is still a popular choice, I want to point out that Microsoft has in recent times committed more resources to their formerly languishing cross-platform ODBC support. The [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh568454) is at the time of writing the best connectivity option for Linux in terms of features and compatibility, and it should avoid the problems with `SET` options having unexpectedly ancient defaults. If your software has ODBC support, it's worth considering.

Comment: Over and above my friend haha! Thank you again.